# itextsharp: Set line width of existing lines in pdf

Tags: itext

I want to use `itextsharp` to set all lines of an existing PDF to a minimum line width, simulating hair line correction of Adobe Pro. I am using itextsharp for the first time and managed to open a PDF, get the page I am interested in and create a filestream to write. I also got the `PdfContentByte` and found many examples to draw new lines and set the line width with `.setlinewidth.`

What I don't know is how to set the line width of existing lines, or even iterate somehow through 'line objects'.

Thanks in advance,

Comment: Parse every contents stream (page content streams and XObjects), write the content streams anew, introduce set line widths before every stroke operators depending on the existence of undesired line widths in the current graphics state. That's feasible, but if you can't achieve this yourself, you'll have to hire someone to do it for you. Solving your problem takes more time than someone is usually willing to spend on a StackOverflow answer.